# Filtering field in DJango in the URL and in the view

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

Lets say I have a model with 2 fields:

```
class Bands(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(db_column='NAME')
    type = models.CharField(db_column='TYPE')
    ...
```

What I want to do is to list all the fields data with just one template. For example:

```
{% block content %}

{{ field_name }}
    <ul>
    {% for band in bands %}
        <li>{{ band }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

So, how should I make my url?

```
url(r'^band/$', views.band, name='band')
```

or

```
url(r'^band/(?P<band>\w+)/$', views.band, name='band')
```

The link to that page would be:

```
<a href="{% url 'band' 'name' %}">Name</a>
```

In the view I'm taking the values as this:

```
def band(request, field):
    results = Results.objects.all()
    names = [n.name for n in results]
    types = [t.type for t in results]

    if field == 'name':
        bands = names
    else:
        bands = types

    return render(request, 'band.html', {'bands': bands, 'field_name': field})
```

Is this the right way to do this (in the view and the url)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the *simplest* thing to do is use the [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.detail.DetailView).

```
from .models import Band

class BandDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Band
```

And in `urls.py` something like:

```
from band.views import BandDetailView
url(r'^band/(?P<pk>\d+)/?$', BandDetailView.as_view(), name='band-detail')
```

And in the template:

```
{% url 'band-detail' pk=1 %}
```

That said, your model doesn't make much sense to me, as does the Led Zeppelin vs. Deep Purple bits in the view. Can you explain your project / need a bit more?

Comment: that was just an example to realize how can I achieve it the right way. I'll try this way and tell you later. Thanks.

Comment: @xRa Gotcha. Don't forget to vote/accept if the answer helped.